# Create a c++ dll with inline assembly

Tags: c++, qt, assembly, dll, hook

What I am trying to is is make a c++ dll file with a mid function hook in it, to watch when a value is changed in a game(Plants Vs Zombies). Now my problem is when the inline assembly is included via a header, when the .dll is built it gives an error
`:-1: error: [release/PVZ_lib.o] Error 1` (PVZ_lib is the name of the cpp file where my main is)

I am using QT Creator as my IDE with MinGW 4.7 compiler.

**Assembly Header**

```
#ifndef ASM_H
#define ASM_H
#include "addr.h"

DWORD scan      =0;
DWORD scanreg   =0;
DWORD scanptr;

void code(void){

    asm("ADD [EAX+0x5560],ECX");

    asm("MOV scanreg,ECX");

    asm("MOV ECX,[EAX+0x5560]");
    asm("CMP ECX,2706");
    asm("JLE SHORT PlantsVs.00430A9D");

    asm("jmp[scan]");


}

#endif // ASM_H
```

**Functions**

```
#include "addr.h"    

void addr::PlaceJMP(BYTE *Address,DWORD jumpto,DWORD lenght){
    DWORD dwoldprotect, dwbkup, dwreladdr;

    VirtualProtect(Address,lenght,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,&dwoldprotect);
    dwreladdr = (DWORD) (jumpto -(DWORD)Address) - 5;
    *Address  = 0xE9l;
    *((DWORD*)(Address+0x1))= dwreladdr;

    for(DWORD x=0x5;x<lenght;x++){
        *(Address+x)=0x90;
    }

    VirtualProtect(Address,lenght,dwoldprotect,&dwbkup);
}

MODULEINFO addr::GetModuleInfo(char *name){
    MODULEINFO modinfo={0};
    HMODULE hModule =GetModuleHandle(name);
    if(hModule == 0){
        return modinfo;
    }

    GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(),hModule, &modinfo,sizeof(MODULEINFO));
    return modinfo;
}

DWORD addr::FindPat(char *module,char *pattern,char *mask){
    MODULEINFO mInfo = GetModuleInfo(module);
    DWORD base =(DWORD)mInfo.lpBaseOfDll;
    DWORD size =(DWORD)mInfo.SizeOfImage;
    DWORD i;
    bool found = true;
    DWORD PatternLenght = (DWORD)strlen(mask);
    for(i=0;i<size-PatternLenght;i++){

        for(DWORD j=0;j<PatternLenght;j++){
            found &=mask[j] == '?' || pattern[j] == *(char*)(base+i+j);
        }
    }
    if(found){
        return base+i;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

**Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include "addr.h"
#include "ASM.h"
addr stuff;

void initHooks(){

        DWORD find = stuff.FindPat("PlantsVsZombies.exe",
                                   "\x01\x88\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8B\x88\x00\x00\x00\x00\x81\xF9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7E\x78",
                                   "xx????xx????xx????xx"
                                   );
    }

    DWORD WINAPI watch(){
        scanptr= scanreg;//+0x3C
        DWORD test=scanptr;

        for(;;Sleep(150)){
            if(scanptr!=test){
              test=scanptr;
                //addr.MsgBoxAddr(1);
            }
        }
    }

    BOOL WINAPI DLLMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD ftwReason,LPVOID lpReserved){
        initHooks();
        switch(ftwReason){
            case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)watch(),NULL,NULL,NULL);
            break;
        }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I have tried formatting the assembler like this.

```
__declspec(naked) void code(void){

    __asm{
         //assembler
    }
}
```

in this format i get the following:

> warning: 'naked' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes] and a few
>   error: was not declared in this scope

Note: i am not familiar with hooking or inline assembly.

What i used to create this code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8PGxbu4EqQ

http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Comment: Is this the smallest compilable example of your code that contain errors?

Comment: GCC does not allow "naked" for "most" platforms. `scanptr<test||scanptr>test` is the same as `scanptr != test`. If this is GCC assembly, then you need `-masm=intel` to use the intel syntax. Otherwise you need to use AT&T syntax..

Comment: In addition to the good points in @brandon 's comment, if you read gcc's much more detailed [inline asm docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), you will see that having multiple asm statements like this (instead of a single, multi-line statement) is a bad idea.  Also, modifying registers (like ecx) without letting gcc know (via contraints, clobbers, etc) is a bad idea.  I suspect that using asm to jump like this can also cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a tool like cheatEngine to find the address that you want to hook and use Visual Studio C++ compiler to do this.

```
#define SOME_OFFSET = 0x5560;

void __declspec(naked) _stdcall MyHack(){
   __asm{
     add [eax+SOME_OFFSET], ecx
     //other stuff...

  }

}
```

Also, whenever you are testing your code, watch how the jump is being performed in the memory with CheatEngine.